# Select Specific data from text file and export it into csv

Tags: powershell, csv, text

I am stuck at a conversion of text file into csv where selected data needs to be put inside that csv. So far I have managed only one line of code that works for me and I am unable to take it further.

**Text file:**

Search: Object: EMP NAMES under /USER/ENT/FOL1

Object: EMP NAMES   Object Location Point Alias EMP name
1SIG_MOU_RM_CTL /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1
1SIG_MOU_COMBINED_ADJ   /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1
1SIG_MOU_CONTROL    /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1
1SIG_MOU_BKR    /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1
1SIG_MOU_MAN_ADJ    /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1
1SIG_MOU_PSS    /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1
1SIG_MOU_REG_MODE   /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1
SIG_MOUD_TUNE   /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_41CONT  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_AUT_MD  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_BASE_MODE   /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_FC1CTRL /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_FC2CTRL /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_PSS_MODE    /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_SS_SIG_FIFO /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_SS_FCR_FIFO /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MOU_SP_TYPE /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
SIG_MAST_BA_CONT    /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     MVAR
SIG_ST_BE_ALG   /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     VALPROF

SIG_SP_SIG_VALPROF  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     VALPROF

SIG_SP_FCR_VALPROF  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     VALPROF

SIG_TRANSFER_MOD_DC_SP  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     RELOC
LVR_MOU_MODULE_CMDS /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1     BOARD
FCN0001 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001    FCN0001_900 SWEEP
FCN0001001  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN0001005  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BOARD
FCN0001008  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN000100A  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BOARD
FCN000100C  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN000100E  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN0001010  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN0001012  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN0001018  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN000101C  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        BIFOLD
FCN0001020  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        CHANGEOVER
FCN0001028  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        HOLD
FCN0001029  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        HOLD
FCN000102A  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0001        HOLD
FCN0002 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002    FCN0002_901 SWEEP
FCN0002001  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002        CLONE
FCN000200B  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002        CLONE
FCN000200D  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002        CLONE
FCN0002013  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002        CLONE
FCN0002017  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002        CLONE
FCN0002019  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002        CLONE
FCN000201B  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0002        CLONE
FCN0003 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0003    FCN0003_301 SWEEP
FCN0003010  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0003        BIFOLD
FCN0003016  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0003        SINGLE
FCN0004 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 2/0004    FCN0004_064 SWEEP
FCN0004005  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 2/0004        QUALITY 
FCN0004006  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 2/0004        QUALITY 
FCN0005 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0005    FCN0005_201 SWEEP
FCN0005007  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0005        SINGLE
FCN0005008  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0005        SINGLE
FCN000500A  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0005        SINGLE
FCN0005010  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0005        SINGLE
FCN0005023  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0005        SINGLE
FCN0006 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0006    FCN0006_204 SWEEP
FCN0006002  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0006        BIFOLD
FCN0006007  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0006        HOLD
FCN0006012  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0006        BIFOLD
FCN0006014  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0006        LOW 
FCN0007 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0007    FCN0007_160 SWEEP
FCN0008 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/0008    FCN0008_161 SWEEP
FCN0009 /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009    FCN0009_303 SWEEP
FCN0009001  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SEQ 
FCN0009016  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        LOW 
FCN0009017  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SUM 
FCN000901C  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        CLONE
FCN000901D  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        OFI 
FCN000901F  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SINGLE
FCN0009026  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SINGLE
FCN0009029  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SINGLE
FCN000902E  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HIGHMON 
FCN0009036  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HIGHMON 
FCN0009038  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SINGLE
FCN0009039  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HIGHMON 
FCN000903A  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SUM 
FCN000903B  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HIGHMON 
FCN000903C  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SINGLE
FCN000903D  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SUM 
FCN000903E  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HIGHMON 
FCN0009043  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SINGLE
FCN000904C  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HOLD
FCN000904D  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HOLD
FCN000904E  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HOLD
FCN000904F  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        HIGH
FCN0009050  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        GAIN
FCN0009051  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 3/0009        SINGLE
FCN000A /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A    FCN000A_150 SWEEP
FCN000A001  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A003  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A005  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD
FCN000A006  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A008  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A00A  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD
FCN000A00D  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD
FCN000A00E  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A010  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A012  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A014  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD
FCN000A017  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A019  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD
FCN000A01C  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A01E  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A020  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A022  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD
FCN000A025  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD
FCN000A027  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A02C  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A02D  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A02F  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        CLONE
FCN000A03A  /USER/ENT/BASE/FOL1/Work Area 5/000A        BIFOLD

So far I am able to read the specific data using:

```
$a = (Get-Content *.txt) | Select-String "ValProf" , "BIFOLD" , "BOARD" | FOREACH {$_ -replace '/User/ENT/Base/'

        [array]$obj += New-Object psobject -Property @{

                 EMP = "Value in first column"
                Name  = "value in second column"


}
}
$a | Select-Object EMP , Name  | Export-Csv Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The intended output will be in a csv format with 2 column headings EMP and Name. EMP shall contain SIG_MOUD_TUNE and Name shall contain BOARD. The output what i am trying to get is :- [image: The output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of `-split` you could use the `-replace` function:

```
Get-Content *.txt | 
    Select-String "HSarna"  , "ValProf"  | 
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '/User/ENT/Base/'}
```

Edit: Based on your new requirements, here the code you need:

```
Get-Content *.txt |
    Select-String "ValProf" , "BIFOLD" , "BOARD" | 
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
                EMP = [regex]::Match($_, '(\w+)').Groups[1].Value
                Name  = [regex]::Match($_, '.*\s+(\w+)$').Groups[1].Value
        }
    }  | 
    Select-Object EMP , Name |
    Export-Csv Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: though it worked flawlessly, but after execution i noticed that in some places in the file '/User/ENT/Base/' is extended by '/User/ENT/Base/root c-001' or basically some additional text including spaces. I am trying incorporate wildcard search, i hope i am doing the right thing.

Comment: If you provide a lot of sample data including the desired output we can find a pattern.

Comment: modified the script as well as added more sample data.This time i have included the way i am trying to get the formatted output in csv.